# Constructing efficient monad instances on `Set` (and other containers with constraints) using the continuation monad

Tags: haskell, complexity-theory, monads, continuations, curry-howard

`Set`, similarly to `[]` has a perfectly defined monadic operations. The problem is that they require that the values satisfy `Ord` constraint, and so it's impossible to define `return` and `>>=` without any constraints. The same problem applies to many other data structures that require some kind of constraints on possible values.

The standard trick (suggested to me in a [haskell-cafe post](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2009-November/068761.html)) is to wrap `Set` into the continuation monad. `ContT` doesn't care if the underlying type functor has any constraints. The constraints become only needed when wrapping/unwrapping `Set`s into/from continuations:

```
import Control.Monad.Cont
import Data.Foldable (foldrM)
import Data.Set

setReturn :: a -> Set a
setReturn = singleton

setBind :: (Ord b) => Set a -> (a -> Set b) -> Set b
setBind set f = foldl' (\s -> union s . f) empty set

type SetM r a = ContT r Set a

fromSet :: (Ord r) => Set a -> SetM r a
fromSet = ContT . setBind

toSet :: SetM r r -> Set r
toSet c = runContT c setReturn
```

This works as needed. For example, we can simulate a non-deterministic function that either increases its argument by 1 or leaves it intact:

```
step :: (Ord r) => Int -> SetM r Int
step i = fromSet $ fromList [i, i + 1]

-- repeated application of step:
stepN :: Int -> Int -> Set Int
stepN times start = toSet $ foldrM ($) start (replicate times step)
```

Indeed, `stepN 5 0` yields `fromList [0,1,2,3,4,5]`. If we used `[]` monad instead, we would get

```
[0,1,1,2,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5]
```

instead.

---

The problem is **efficiency**. If we call `stepN 20 0` the output takes a few seconds and `stepN 30 0` doesn't finish within a reasonable amount of time. It turns out that all `Set.union` operations are performed at the end, instead of performing them after each monadic computation. The result is that exponentially many `Set`s are constructed and `union`ed only at the end, which is unacceptable for most tasks.

Is there any way around it, to make this construction efficient? I tried but without success.

(I even suspect that there could be some kinds of theoretical limits following from Curry-Howard isomorphism and [Glivenko's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-negation_translation#Propositional_logic). Glivenko's theorem says that for any propositional tautology *φ* the formula *¬¬φ* can be proved in intuitionistic logic. However, I suspect that the length of the proof (in normal form) can be exponentially long. So, perhaps, there could be cases when wrapping a computation into the continuation monad will make it exponentially longer?)

Comment: Well, it seems to me that there can't be a truly efficient `Monad` instance for `Set` unless there is also an efficient `Functor` instance. And I'm having a hard time seeing how you can have an efficient `fmap` for `Set`.  [The existing `map` for `Set` is n * log n.](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.4.2.1/doc/html/Data-Set.html#g:7) `Set`'s implemented as strict trees, so laziness won't help you ever either.

Comment: I think the problem is that the monad doesn't "know" that numbers have `Ord` or even `Eq`.

Comment: @LuisCasillas An additional _log n_ factor would be OK, the thing that concerns me is the exponential blow-up.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Monads are one particular way of structuring and sequencing computations. The bind of a monad cannot magically restructure your computation so as to happen in a more efficient way. There are two problems with the way you structure your computation.

1. When evaluating `stepN 20 0`, the result of `step 0` will be computed 20 times. This is because each step of the computation produces 0 as one alternative, which is then fed to the next step, which also produces 0 as alternative, and so on...

   Perhaps a bit of memoization here can help.
2. A much bigger problem is the effect of `ContT` on the structure of your computation. With a bit of equational reasoning, expanding out the result of `replicate 20 step`, the definition of `foldrM` and simplifying as many times as necessary, we can see that `stepN 20 0` is equivalent to:

   ```
   (...(return 0 >>= step) >>= step) >>= step) >>= ...)
   ```

   All parentheses of this expression associate to the left. That's great, because it means that the RHS of each occurrence of `(>>=)` is an elementary computation, namely `step`, rather than a composed one. However, zooming in on the definition of `(>>=)` for `ContT`,

   ```
   m >>= k = ContT $ \c -> runContT m (\a -> runContT (k a) c)
   ```

   we see that when evaluating a chain of `(>>=)` associating to the left, each bind will push a new computation onto the current continuation `c`. To illustrate what is going on,  we can use again a bit of equational reasoning, expanding out this definition for `(>>=)` and the definition for `runContT`, and simplifying, yielding:

   ```
   setReturn 0 `setBind`
       (\x1 -> step x1 `setBind`
           (\x2 -> step x2 `setBind` (\x3 -> ...)...)
   ```

   Now, for each occurrence of `setBind`, let's ask ourselves what the RHS argument is. For the leftmost occurrence, the RHS argument is the whole rest of the computation after `setReturn 0`. For the second occurrence, it's everything after `step x1`, etc. Let's zoom in to the definition of `setBind`:

   ```
   setBind set f = foldl' (\s -> union s . f) empty set
   ```

   Here `f` represents all the rest of the computation, *everything* on the right hand side of an occurrence of `setBind`. That means that at each step, we are capturing the rest of the computation as `f`, and applying `f` as many times as there are elements in `set`. The computations are not elementary as before, but rather composed, and these computations will be duplicated many times.

The crux of the problem is that the `ContT` monad transformer is transforming the initial structure of the computation, which you meant as a left associative chain of `setBind`'s, into a computation with a different structure, ie a right associative chain. This is after all perfectly fine, because one of the monad laws says that, for every `m`, `f` and `g` we have

```
(m >>= f) >>= g = m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)
```

However, the monad laws do not impose that the complexity remain the same on each side of the equations of each law. And indeed, in this case, the left associative way of structuring this computation is a lot more efficient. The left associative chain of `setBind`'s evaluates in no time, because only elementary subcomputations are duplicated.

It turns out that other solutions shoehorning `Set` into a monad also suffer from the same problem. In particular, the [set-monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/set-monad) package, yields similar runtimes. The reason being, that it too, rewrites left associative expressions into right associative ones.

I think you have put the finger on a **very important yet rather subtle problem** with insisting that `Set` obeys a `Monad` interface. And I don't think it can be solved. The problem is that the type of the bind of a monad needs to be

```
(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

ie no class constraint allowed on either `a` or `b`. That means that we cannot nest binds on the left, without first invoking the monad laws to rewrite into a right associative chain. Here's why: given `(m >>= f) >>= g`, the type of the computation `(m >>= f)` is of the form `m b`. A value of the computation `(m >>= f)` is of type `b`. But because we can't hang any class constraint onto the type variable `b`, we can't know that the value we got satisfies an `Ord` constraint, and therefore cannot use this value as the element of a set on which we want to be able to compute `union`'s.

Comment: I think this transformation is similar to the one described [here(pdf)](http://www.iai.uni-bonn.de/~jv/mpc08.pdf) using free monads and Codensity (see also Edward Kmett's blog), although in this case making things right-associative is hurting things rather than improving them. I wonder if there is a similar but opposite transformation possible? (I've just been starting to study `Free` so I'm not much help, sorry)

Answer (score 11):

Recently on Haskell Cafe [Oleg gave an example](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2013-April/107607.html) how to implement the `Set` monad efficiently. Quoting:

> ... And yet, the efficient genuine Set monad is possible.
>
> ... 
>   Enclosed is the efficient genuine Set monad. I wrote it in direct style (it seems to be faster, anyway). The key is to use the optimized choose function when we can.
>
> ```
>   {-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}
>
>   module SetMonadOpt where
>
>   import qualified Data.Set as S
>   import Control.Monad
>
>   data SetMonad a where
>       SMOrd :: Ord a => S.Set a -> SetMonad a
>       SMAny :: [a] -> SetMonad a
>
>   instance Monad SetMonad where
>       return x = SMAny [x]
>
>       m >>= f = collect . map f $ toList m
>
>   toList :: SetMonad a -> [a]
>   toList (SMOrd x) = S.toList x
>   toList (SMAny x) = x
>
>   collect :: [SetMonad a] -> SetMonad a
>   collect []  = SMAny []
>   collect [x] = x
>   collect ((SMOrd x):t) = case collect t of
>                            SMOrd y -> SMOrd (S.union x y)
>                            SMAny y -> SMOrd (S.union x (S.fromList y))
>   collect ((SMAny x):t) = case collect t of
>                            SMOrd y -> SMOrd (S.union y (S.fromList x))
>                            SMAny y -> SMAny (x ++ y)
>
>   runSet :: Ord a => SetMonad a -> S.Set a
>   runSet (SMOrd x) = x
>   runSet (SMAny x) = S.fromList x
>
>   instance MonadPlus SetMonad where
>       mzero = SMAny []
>       mplus (SMAny x) (SMAny y) = SMAny (x ++ y)
>       mplus (SMAny x) (SMOrd y) = SMOrd (S.union y (S.fromList x))
>       mplus (SMOrd x) (SMAny y) = SMOrd (S.union x (S.fromList y))
>       mplus (SMOrd x) (SMOrd y) = SMOrd (S.union x y)
>
>   choose :: MonadPlus m => [a] -> m a
>   choose = msum . map return
>
>
>   test1 = runSet (do
>     n1 <- choose [1..5]
>     n2 <- choose [1..5]
>     let n = n1 + n2
>     guard $ n < 7
>     return n)
>   -- fromList [2,3,4,5,6]
>
>   -- Values to choose from might be higher-order or actions
>   test1' = runSet (do
>     n1 <- choose . map return $ [1..5]
>     n2 <- choose . map return $ [1..5]
>     n  <- liftM2 (+) n1 n2
>     guard $ n < 7
>     return n)
>   -- fromList [2,3,4,5,6]
>
>   test2 = runSet (do
>     i <- choose [1..10]
>     j <- choose [1..10]
>     k <- choose [1..10]
>     guard $ i*i + j*j == k * k
>     return (i,j,k))
>   -- fromList [(3,4,5),(4,3,5),(6,8,10),(8,6,10)]
>
>   test3 = runSet (do
>     i <- choose [1..10]
>     j <- choose [1..10]
>     k <- choose [1..10]
>     guard $ i*i + j*j == k * k
>     return k)
>   -- fromList [5,10]
>
>   -- Test by Petr Pudlak
>
>   -- First, general, unoptimal case
>   step :: (MonadPlus m) => Int -> m Int
>   step i = choose [i, i + 1]
>
>   -- repeated application of step on 0:
>   stepN :: Int -> S.Set Int
>   stepN = runSet . f
>     where
>     f 0 = return 0
>     f n = f (n-1) >>= step
>
>   -- it works, but clearly exponential
>   {-
>   *SetMonad> stepN 14
>   fromList [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
>   (0.09 secs, 31465384 bytes)
>   *SetMonad> stepN 15
>   fromList [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
>   (0.18 secs, 62421208 bytes)
>   *SetMonad> stepN 16
>   fromList [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
>   (0.35 secs, 124876704 bytes)
>   -}
>
>   -- And now the optimization
>   chooseOrd :: Ord a => [a] -> SetMonad a
>   chooseOrd x = SMOrd (S.fromList x)
>
>   stepOpt :: Int -> SetMonad Int
>   stepOpt i = chooseOrd [i, i + 1]
>
>   -- repeated application of step on 0:
>   stepNOpt :: Int -> S.Set Int
>   stepNOpt = runSet . f
>     where
>     f 0 = return 0
>     f n = f (n-1) >>= stepOpt
>
>   {-
>   stepNOpt 14
>   fromList [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
>   (0.00 secs, 515792 bytes)
>   stepNOpt 15
>   fromList [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
>   (0.00 secs, 515680 bytes)
>   stepNOpt 16
>   fromList [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
>   (0.00 secs, 515656 bytes)
>
>   stepNOpt 30
>   fromList [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]
>   (0.00 secs, 1068856 bytes)
>   -}
> ```

Comment: I don't think that's right. `liftM id` can change the result.

Comment: @PyRulez Can you please elaborate on that, what `liftM id` you have in mind?

Comment: `liftM id` must equal `id` by the Monad laws. `liftM id :: SetMonad a -> SetMonad a` does not.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your performance problems in this case are due to the use of `Cont`

```
step' :: Int -> Set Int
step' i = fromList [i,i + 1]

foldrM' f z0 xs = Prelude.foldl f' setReturn xs z0
  where f' k x z = f x z `setBind` k

stepN' :: Int -> Int -> Set Int
stepN' times start = foldrM' ($) start (replicate times step')
```

gets similar performance to the `Cont` based implementation but occurs entirely in the `Set` "restricted monad"

I am not sure if I believe your claim about Glivenko's theorem leading to exponential increase in (normalized) proof size--at least in the Call-By-Need context.  That is because we can arbitrarily reuse subproofs (and our logic is second order, we need only a single proof of `forall a. ~~(a \/ ~a)`).  Proofs are not trees, they are graphs (sharing).

In general, you are likely to see performance costs from `Cont` wrapping `Set` but they can usually be avoided via

```
smash :: (Ord r, Ord k) => SetM r r -> SetM k r
smash = fromSet . toSet
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try to elaborate a non-monadic version of the problem (I already have a solution that's fast as expected, I'll try to compare it closely with yours). Concerning Glivenko's theorem, it was just an idea, I'm not sure about that at all.

Comment: Thinking about it, I still think the length of a _normalized_ proof can be exponential (which correspond to the running time of a program). Normalization is what makes the proof graph to expand. For example `\c -> c (Right (\a -> c (Left a))) :: (Either a (a -> Void) -> Void) -> Void` is short. But, `c` is applied twice, to different arguments. So when this term is applied and we get a specific function for `c`, the computation in `c` must be run twice, it cannot be shared. The same thing happens when a proof is converted to a normal form.

Answer (score 1):

I found out another possibility, based on GHC's [ConstraintKinds](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/constraint-kind.html) extension. The idea is to redefine `Monad` so that it includes a parametric constraint on allowed values:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax #-}

import qualified Data.Foldable as F
import qualified Data.Set as S
import Prelude hiding (Monad(..), Functor(..))

class CFunctor m where
    -- Each instance defines a constraint it valust must satisfy:
    type Constraint m a
    -- The default is no constraints.
    type Constraint m a = ()
    fmap   :: (Constraint m a, Constraint m b) => (a -> b) -> (m a -> m b)
class CFunctor m => CMonad (m :: * -> *) where
    return :: (Constraint m a) => a -> m a
    (>>=)  :: (Constraint m a, Constraint m b) => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
    fail   :: String -> m a
    fail   = error

-- [] instance
instance CFunctor [] where
    fmap = map
instance CMonad [] where
    return  = (: [])
    (>>=)   = flip concatMap

-- Set instance
instance CFunctor S.Set where
    -- Sets need Ord.
    type Constraint S.Set a = Ord a
    fmap = S.map
instance CMonad S.Set where
    return  = S.singleton
    (>>=)   = flip F.foldMap

-- Example:

-- prints fromList [3,4,5]
main = print $ do
    x <- S.fromList [1,2]
    y <- S.fromList [2,3]
    return $ x + y
```

(The problem with this approach is in the case the monadic values are functions, such as `m (a -> b)`, because they can't satisfy constraints like `Ord (a -> b)`. So one can't use combinators like `<*>` (or `ap`) for this constrained `Set` monad.)