# Is there something like a continuation Arrow transformer?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, continuations, arrows, category-theory

The [`ContT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Cont.html#v:ContT) monad transformer has a interesting property: If there is a `* -> *` type such as `Set`, that has well-defined monadic operations, but can't have a `Monad` instance due to some constraints (here `Ord a`), it's possible to wrap it in `ContT` (`ContT r Set`) to get a monad instance, and defer the constraints outside it, like when we inject `Set` into `ContT r Set`.
See [Constructing efficient monad instances on `Set` using the continuation monad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12183656/1333025).

Is there something similar for arrows? An [arrow transformer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arrows-0.4.4.1/docs/Control-Arrow-Transformer.html#t:ArrowTransformer) that'd allow to wrap an "almost arrow" into it, getting a valid `Arrow` instance, and defer problematic constraints to the part where we inject the "almost arrow" into it?

For example, if we had a type `AlmostArrow :: * -> * -> *` for which we'd have the usual `Arrow` operations, but with constraints, such as

```
arr' :: (Ord a, Ord b) => (a -> b) -> AlmostArrow a b
(>>>') :: (Ord a, Ord b, Ord c) => AlmostArrow a b -> AlmostArrow b c -> AlmostArrow a c
```

As a bonus, if yes, is there some nifty, generic category-theory way how to derive both `ContT` and such an arrow transformer?

Comment: A free arrow would surely do the trick.  Then you just have to do some junk to make it efficient.