# Is 'Chaining operations' the "only" thing that the Monad class solves?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

*To clarify the question: it is about the merits of the monad type class (as opposed to just its instances without the unifying class).*

After having read many references (see below),
I came to the conclusion that, actually, the **monad class** is there to solve **only** one, but **big and crucial**, problem: **the 'chaining' of functions on types with context**. Hence, the famous sentence "monads are programmable semicolons".
In fact, a monad can be viewed as [an array of functions with helper operations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21813760/286335).

I insist on the difference between the monad **class**, understood as a general interface for other types; and these other types instantiating the class (thus, "monadic types").

I understand that the monad class by itself, only solves the chaining of operators because mainly, it only mandates its type instances
to have `bind >>=` and `return`, and tell us how they must behave. And as a bonus, the compiler greatyly helps the coding providing `do` notation for monadic types.

On the other hand,
it is **each** individual type instantiating the monad class which solves **each concrete problem**, **but not merely for being a instance of Monad**. For instance `Maybe` solves "how a function returns a value or an error", `State` solves "how to have functions with global state", `IO` solves "how to interact with the outside world", and so on. All theses classes encapsulate a value within a context.

But soon or later, we will need to chain operations on such context-types. I.e., we will need to organize calls to functions on these types in a particular sequence (for an example of such a problem, please read the example about multivalued functions in [You could have invented monads](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html)).

And you get solved the problem of chaining, if you have each type be an instance of the monad class.
For the chaining to work you need `>>=` just with the exact signature it has, no other. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221705/on-the-signature-of-monad-operator)).

Therefore, I guess that the next time you define a context data type T for solving something, if you need to sequence calls of functions (on values of T) consider making T an instance of `Monad` (if you need "chaining with choice" and if you can benefit from the `do` notation). And to make sure you are doing it right, check that T satisfies the [monad laws](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_laws)

**Then, I ask two questions to the Haskell experts:**

1. **A concrete question: is there any other problem that the monad class solves by ifself (leaving apart monadic classes)? If any, then, how it compares in relevance to the problem of chaining operations?**
2. An optional general question: are my conclusions right, am I misunderstanding something?

### References

#### Tutorials

- [Monads in pictures](http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html) Definitely worth it; read this one first.
- [Fistful of monads](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads)
- [You could have invented monads](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html)
- [Monads are trees](https://github.com/dpiponi/grafting3/blob/master/monads.pdf) (pdf)

#### StackOverflow Questions & Answers

- [How to detect a monad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495627/how-to-detect-a-monad)
- [On the signature of >>= monad operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221705/on-the-signature-of-monad-operator)

Comment: Just for clarification, are you wondering about the merits of the monad type class (as opposed to just its instances without the unifying class), or the monad concept (as defined by the monad operations and laws)?

Comment: @ollanta about the merits of the monad type class (as opposed to just its instances without the unifying class),

Comment: Then I would say it doesn't solve any problem except boilerplate, like all type classes. I don't think anyone would say the monad type class solves X problems. Rather it reifies a useful concept in Haskell, so that we can talk about functions on monads (understanding their possibilities and limitations), instead of functions on types and more functions on those types implementing a specialized protocol. It's all about making abstraction beautiful.

Comment: From the 2 answers given: "the monad class allows its instance types to reuse the code for chaining operations, and makes it possible that a chained operation depends on the result of the previous one".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're definitely on to something in the way that you're stating this—there are many things that `Monad` means and you've separated them out well.

That said, I would definitely say that chaining operations is *not* the primary thing solved by Monads. That can be solved using plain Functors (with some trouble) or easily with Applicatives. **You need to use the full monad spec when "chaining with choice".** In particular, the tension between `Applicative` and `Monad` comes from `Applicative` needing to know the entire structure of the side-effecting computation statically. `Monad` can change that structure at runtime and thus sacrifices some analyzability for power.

---

To make the point more clear, **the only place you deal with a Monad but not any *specific* monad is if you're defining something with polymorphism constrained to be a Monad**. This shows up repeatedly in the `Control.Monad` module, so we can examine some examples from there.

```
sequence     :: [m a] -> m [a]
forever      :: m a   -> m b
foldM        :: (a -> b -> m a) -> a -> [b] -> m a
```

Immediately, we can throw out `sequence` as being particular to `Monad` since there's a corresponding function in `Data.Traversable`, `sequenceA` which has a type slightly more general than `Applicative f => [f a] -> f [a]`. This ought to be a clear indicator that **`Monad` isn't the only way to sequence things**.

Similarly, we can define `foreverA` as follows

```
foreverA :: Applicative f => f a -> f b
foreverA f = flip const <$> f <*> foreverA f
```

So more ways to sequence non-`Monad` types. But we run into trouble with `foldM`

```
foldM             :: (Monad m) => (a -> b -> m a) -> a -> [b] -> m a
foldM _ a []      =  return a
foldM f a (x:xs)  =  f a x >>= \fax -> foldM f fax xs
```

If we try to translate this definition to `Applicative` style we might write

```
foldA             :: (Applicative f) => (a -> b -> f a) -> a -> [b] -> f a
foldA _ a []      =  pure a
foldA f a (x:xs)  = foldA f <$> f a x <*> xs
```

But Haskell will rightfully complain that this doesn't typecheck--each recursive call to `foldA` tries to put another "layer" of `f` on the result. With `Monad` we could `join` those layers down, but `Applicative` is too weak.

---

So how does this translate to `Applicative`s restricting us from runtime choices? Well, that's exactly what we express with `foldM`, a monadic computation `(a -> b -> m a)` which depends upon its `a` argument, a result from a prior monadic computation. That kind of thing simply doesn't have any meaning in the more purely sequential world of `Applicative`.

Comment: In summary you need a monad when "the next action depends on the value returned by the previous action".  You can get away with an applicative when "the next value depends on the previous value, but the action run to generate that value does not".

Comment: ... and a functor is just when you don't need to create any new side effects at all.

Comment: @jozefg Well, you still can use `Fix` to create a whole nested set of effects that you interpret elsewhere. `data SayHi a = SayHi a | Done`, `io :: Fix SayHi -> IO (); io (Fix Done) = return (); io (Fix SayHi next) = putStrLn "hi" >> io next`.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson But the `Functor` type class -- and in particular its only method `fmap` -- doesn't let you introduce new "side effects" into an existing `Fix SayHi` value. That's the point I think jozefg was trying to make. Of course specific functors can have functions that introduce new side effects, but that's beside the point.

Comment: That's true. I think I'm stuck on thinking about that due to trying to be explicit about what exactly causes sequencing of effects. Nesting of Functors is one blind way to achieve that without any more structure.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson: you may already know this, but that's exactly what a "free monad" is.

Comment: @JohnL Not always. There are nested functors which perform effects but aren't free monads. For instance, given `data GetC a = GetC (Char -> a)` then `f = GetC (const f) :: Fix GetC` is `forever getChar` and not a free monad, I don't believe.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson: true, it depends on how you do the nesting.  But the usual `Free` nesting will create a free monad for any functor.

Comment: I feel like this could be simplified a lot just by using `(*>)` for the applicative sequencing operator, so that e.g. `foreverA f = f *> foreverA f` etc.

Answer (score 8):

To solve the problem of chaining operations on an individual monadic type, it's not at all necessary to make it an instance of `Monad` and be sure the monad laws are satisfied. You could just implement a chaining operation directly on your type.

It would probably be very similar to the monadic bind, but not necessarily exactly the same (recall that bind for lists is `concatMap`, a function that exists anyway, but with the arguments in a different order). And you wouldn't have to worry about the monad laws, because you would have a slightly different interface for each type, so they wouldn't have any common requirements.

To ask what problem the `Monad` type class *itself* solves, look at all the functions (in `Control.Monad` and else where) that work on values in *any* monadic type. The problem solved is code reuse! `Monad` is exactly the part of all the monadic types that is common to each and every one of them. That part is sufficient on its own to write useful computations. All of these functions *could* be implemented for any individual monadic type (often more directly), but they've *already* been implemented for *all* monadic types, even the ones that don't exist yet.

You don't write a `Monad` instance so that you can chain operations on your type (often you already have a way of chaining, in fact). You write a `Monad` instance for all the code that automatically comes along with the `Monad` instance. `Monad` isn't about solving *any* problem for any *single* type, it's about a way of viewing many disparate types as instances of a single unifying concept.

Comment: Thanks. I think that your point that the Monad class is for "reusing the code that allows chaining operations" is not explicitly stated in my question (only implicit) and that it is worth to stress it.