# Examples of Functors without Applicatives

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative

Are there any good examples of `Functor`s which are not `Applicative`s? By good, I'm seeking non-trivial (not `Const Void`) examples which don't need appeals to `undefined`. If there are none is there any method of proving that the space there is uninteresting?

This is similar to [Good examples of Not a Functor/Functor/Applicative/Monad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220436/good-examples-of-not-a-functor-functor-applicative-monad), but it wasn't completely resolved there.

As a follow-up question, are there any interesting examples of `Functor`s which might be left without `Applicative` instances due to having far too many non-canonical `Applicative` instances to be meaningful? For instance, "extended `Maybe`" is a bit boring

```
data MayB a = Jus a | Nothing1 | Nothing2 | Nothing3 | ...

instance Applicative MayB where
  pure = Jus
  Jus f <*> Jus x = Jus (f x)
  Jus f <*> n     = n
  n     <*> Jus x = n
  n1    <*> n2    = methodOfResolvingNothingWhatsoever n1 n2
```

Are there examples where the variations of the `Applicative` instance are more material?

Comment: As a side note, `data MayB a = Jus a | Nothin Int` and `Nothin n1 <*> Nothin n2 = Nothin $ max n1 n2` is how I'd implement it.  Then you have a notion of the level of failure where the higher level takes precedence.  Not sure where this is useful, but it's easy to encode.

Comment: Defining uninteresting would be good. To my knowledge, `Cont m` is an applicative iff `m` is a monoid so there's a lot of functors-not-applicatives there. Essentially anything with a lot of "structure" unrelated to the parameter which we've defined functor over is going to have a hard time being an applicative.

Comment: @bheklilr That's sensible, there's also the "purely-applicative Either" `data Eit b a = L b | R a` with `instance Monoid b => Applicative (Either b) where L b1 <*> L b2 = L (b1 <> b2)`. Generally, though, there are just a whole lot of ways to merge failures and "purely applicative Either" is the closest thing I know to a canonical method.

Comment: @jozefg That's true and I don't much know a good way to define "uninteresting". I think your point about structure holds generally. I'd just like to motivate the need for a `Functor` typeclass and not just an `Applicative` one that includes `fmap`.

Comment: @jozefg: `(a -> m) -> m` can be given an `Applicative` instance (modulo wrapping it in a `newtype`) for any `m` that has an associative binary operation with an identity, not just ones that happen to have been given a `Monoid` instance.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson I made an attempt to make my thought a bit clearer, not sure if I succeeded.

Comment: I think `Const` is more interesting than it's given credit for. The connections to big products and general lens uses demonstrate how common it is to have structure beyond the functor parameter.

Comment: @jozefg that's wrong. In Haskell, all Monads are Applicatives.

Comment: @SassaNF That was a mistake sorry, I had meant `Const`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main place where I see functor but not applicatives is in large product types. Consider something like

```
 data Mean where
    Unfair :: Monad a => a () -> Mean
 data Foo a = Bar Int Mean a
```

This is easily a functor, but there's no way to make this an applicative because

```
 (Bar i g f) (Bar i' g' a) = Bar ??? ??? (f a)
```

We can only fill in our `???`s with something that's a monoid-like in at least one way and `Mean` never is since we have no way of specifying something to combine two values of arbitrary types `g :: a` and `g' :: b` in an associative way.

Additionally, we need the `mempty` or something like it for `pure :: a -> f a`. We're given an `a` so most of the data type that involves an `a` is trivial to construct, but the rest needs a sane "empty" value.

So if we smashed applicative and functor into one large type class, most of `lens` would fall apart because most of the useful cases for lens involve situations just like these, where there isn't a sane `Applicative` instance.

So to put this in a hand-wavey squishy way: When there's a lot of "stuff" in a type that isn't directly to do with the type parameter applicative is defined over, we need a way to merge all of this "stuff" which isn't always possible.

Comment: `Int -> Bool` can be made a monoid in many ways.  `Bool` can be made a monoid in four ways I think, and then you take the product `Int`-many times.

Comment: `instance Monoid (Int -> Bool) where { mempty = const False; mappend f1 f2 = \x -> f1 x || f2 x }`

Comment: You can also always define the Leftmost monoid: `Bar i g f <*> Bar _ _ a = Bar i g (f a)`

Comment: Is that really a monoid?  It doesn't seem to have an identity, in general.  This will prevent you from defining `pure`.

Comment: Losing the notion of a "single-target `Lens`" is pretty important—even if there were no `Functor`s without `Applicative`s then `forall f . Functor f => f` would still be a very different type than `forall f . Applicative f => f`. It doesn't help at all with the argument I was trying to research for, but that doesn't mean it's not very true.

Comment: @TomEllis Er, I spoke imprecisely—my definition defines only the semigroup part, but you're good with these concrete types since there are `2^N * N` `mempty`'s possible here: `pure = Bar 0 (const True)`

Comment: I'm saying the "Leftmost monoid" isn't a monoid.  Although there may be many choices you could make for the identity, none of them satisfies the monoid laws.

Comment: Oh, apologies. You're absolutely correct. You need the `Maybe`.

Comment: @TomEllis Oh you're totally right, that was just careless mistake on my part, I'll edit with an example of something that's not a monoid :)

Comment: @jozefg Your `Monad a => a -> Mean` doesn't kind-check

Answer (score 3):

A very important (if unfair) example is

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data AFunctor a = forall f . Functor f => AFunctor { unFunct :: f a }
```