# Example of a matrix as Applicative functor

Tags: matrix, functional-programming, applicative

I already asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27363061/matrix-as-applicative-functor-which-is-not-monad) but it was not clear enough, so I decided to rephrase it.

I know that a matrix is an `applicative functor` but not a monad. I am wondering if there is a simple and practical example of `<*>` for matrices.

Answer (score 3):

A possible `Applicative` instance for matrices would be to make it analogous to [ZipList](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList). With `F` a matrix of functions, and `X` a matrix of values, `F <*> X` applies each function in `F` pointwise to each value in `X`. The result is truncated in each dimension to fit the shortest matrix. `pure f` gives an infinite matrix with `f` at each point. As an example example, the pointwise matrix multiplication is then `(*) <$> A <*> B`.

In stead of truncation and working with infinity, you could fix the shape of the matrix by using a phantom type parameter as used in `accelerate`. Of course, then you could also declare a Monad instance just like with fixed size ziplists.