# Monad More Powerful than Applicative

Tags: haskell

[Typeclassopedia](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia)'s Chapter 5.3 notes:

> Intuitively, it is this ability to use the output from previous
>   computations to decide what computations to run next that makes Monad
>   more powerful than Applicative.

This example demonstrates this intuition to me:

```
ghci> Just 100 >>= (\x -> if (x == 100) then Nothing else Just x) 
Nothing
```

I don't know (or expect that it's possible based on the above explanation) how to use `(<*>)` to achieve the same, above code.

Are there any other, more precise/strong examples that demonstrate the above text in Typeclassopedia?

Comment: ...and see also [examples of data structures that are at each stage in the chain functor -> applicative -> monad](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7220436/791604).

Answer (score 4):

Not really an example, but the exact property that you're looking for is that you can't write `join :: Applicative f => f (f a) -> f a` but you can write it if you change the constraint to `Monad`. In fact, if you just add this function to an applicative it immediately becomes as powerful as a Monad because with that you can define `return = pure` and `m >>= f = join (fmap f m)`.

I can't remember on top of my head what the laws for join where, but it's mostly common sense stuff like `join (return (return a)) == return a`.

Comment: Common sense stuff indeed: `join . return = id`, `join . fmap return = id` and `join . fmap join = join . join`.