# Why is `pure` only required for Applicative and not already for Functor?

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory

Reading [this Wikibook about Haskell and Category Theory basics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory), I learn about Functors:

> A functor is essentially a transformation between categories, so given
>   categories C and D, a functor F : C -> D
>
> maps any object A in C to F(A), in D.
>
> maps morphisms f : A -> B in C to F(f) : F(A) -> F(B) in D.

... which sounds all nice. Later an example is provided:

> Let's have a sample instance, too:

```
instance Functor Maybe where
  fmap f (Just x) = Just (f x)
  fmap _ Nothing  = Nothing
```

> Here's the key part: the type constructor Maybe takes any type T to a
>   new type, Maybe T. Also, fmap restricted to Maybe types takes a
>   function a -> b to a function Maybe a -> Maybe b. But that's it! We've
>   defined two parts, something that takes objects in Hask to objects in
>   another category (that of Maybe types and functions defined on Maybe
>   types), and something that takes morphisms in Hask to morphisms in
>   this category. So Maybe is a functor.

I understand how the definition of `fmap` is key. I am confused about how the "type constructor Maybe" provides the first part. I would have rather expected something like `pure`.

If I get it right, `Maybe` rather maps `C` to `D`. (Thus being a morphism on category level, which might be a requirement for a Functor)

I guess you could rephrase my question like this: Is there a Functor that does not have an obvious implementation of `pure`?

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful answers. I selected the most detailed one to be "correct".

Comment: One simple `Functor` that does not admit `pure` is `data Void a`. The instance looks like `instance Functor Void where { fmap f x = case x of {} }`. (I'm not making this an answer because I don't think this example is particularly enlightening, even though it answers the only question you actually ask in the body.)

Comment: @DanielWagner I think that's up to isomorphism the *only* `Functor` that doesn't admit `pure`: if you have *any* value `v` in the `Functor` you can define `pure x = x <$ v`. And I think every choice for `pure` is of this form, too. Of course this is not usually very unique.

Comment: "_takes objects in Hask to objects in another category (that of Maybe types and functions defined on Maybe types)_"
I think you are confusing the codomain and the image. The codomain here is the same as the domain, it's Hask, so we are talking about an endofunctor. The _image_ of Hask under Maybe is a _subset_ of the codomain -- all the Maybe types. You can easily convince yourself that Maybe doesn't take you out of Hask because you can apply Maybe multiple times -- Maybe (Mabe a), etc. -- the inner Maybe is still in the domain of Maybe.

Comment: @BartoszMilewski You are right, that was my confusion. And it has been clarified by the answers below. Am I supposed to correct my question (does not seem necessary to me)?

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I disagree with that statement, there are plenty of functors that don't admit a `pure`. Here are a couple examples: `instance Functor ((,) a)` has `fmap f (a, b) = (a, f b)`, but how would you implement `pure`? `pure x = (error "shit", x)`. If you managed to implement `pure` you could obtain `magic = fst . pure ()` `magic :: a` which is a sort of "proof" that such a `pure` would inherently involve `_|_`. (I realize `Monoid a => (,) a` admits a `pure`, but `(,) a` does not. Another example is `instance Functor (Map k)`, and yet another is `instance Functor (Const m)`.

Comment: @semicolon I think you have to pick one `a`: I am making no claim about polymorphic type constructors. If `a` has a value without bottoms then clearly you have a `pure` without bottoms too. And if `a` has no value, then it's isomorphic to `Void`. But I see now that laziness complicates matters, since `(error "shit", x)` isn't itself bottom in Haskell. I think for these kinds of questions it is typical to ignore all bottoms (otherwise you could just say `pure x = undefined` and be done with it), and then I think my claim is still true for any monomorphic example.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Cool, sure it might be true for any monomorphic example. Too bad that doesn't matter because a huge amount of functors are not defined in a monomorphic way, and this question is talking about why `pure` is not in `Functor`, which it very much SHOULD NOT be. And even examples that are monomorphic don't necessarily have a "best" default. For example with lists `pure 5 :: ZipList Int` and `pure 5 :: [Int]` are very very different, but both crucial for their respective `Applicative` instances.

Comment: @Bartosz Is it reasonable to talk about types under `Maybe` as their own category (a subcategory of Hask, to be sure)? If so the quote is perfectly correct. That's always how I've viewed Haskell Functors, rather than as endofunctors. They *can* be viewed as endofunctors of course, but because a type constructor always creates new types most endofunctors on Hask are not expressible as Haskell Functors.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you're getting confused between types and values. Here's the definition of a functor:

> Let *C* and *D* be [categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics)). A **functor** *F* from *C* to *D* is a mapping that:
>
> - associates to each object *X ∈ C* an object *F(X) ∈ D*.
> - associates to each morphism *f : X → Y ∈ C* a morphism *F(f) : F(X) → F(Y) ∈ D* such that the following conditions hold:
>
>   - *F(id : X → X) = id : F(X) → F(X)* for every object *X ∈ C*.
>   - *F(g ∘ f) = F(g) ∘ F(f)* for all morphisms *f : X → Y* and *g : Y → Z*.

A category consists of objects and morphisms between objects.

All code in Haskell is a part of [*Hask*](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory#Hask.2C_the_Haskell_category), the Haskell category. In *Hask*:

1. Types are objects.
2. Functions are morphisms between types.

Hence, all `Functor` instances in Haskell are functors from Hask to Hask (i.e. they are endofunctors).

To put it more rigorously, for all instances of `Functor` in Haskell:

1. `C = Hask`.
2. `D = Hask`.

Now, each functor *F* is a mapping that associates to each object *X ∈ C* an object *F(X) ∈ D*.

1. Note that *X* and *F(X)* are objects of *C* and *D* respectively.
2. Since both *C* and *D* are *Hask*, both *X* and *F(X)* are types and not values.
3. Thus, *F : Type → Type* or in Haskell `f : * -> *`.

Indeed, this is precisely how the `Functor` type class is defined in Haskell:

```hs
class Functor (f : * -> *) where
    fmap :: (x -> y) -> (f x -> f y)
```

Here, `fmap` is the second part of the functor. It's a function from values to values. However, the `Functor` itself is a type constructor (i.e. a mapping from types to types). This is the reason `Maybe` is a functor and `[]` is a functor but `Maybe Int` and `[Int]` are not functors.

Note that `pure` does not form the first part of the functor definition because it's a mapping from an instance of *X* to an instance of *F(X)* (i.e. it's a function from values to values). However, we need a mapping from *X* to *F(X)* (i.e. a mapping from types to types).

Answer (score 4):

> If I get it right, `Maybe` rather maps `C` to `D`. (Thus being a morphism on category level, which might be a requirement for a Functor)

Not really, as `C` and `D` there are categories, and not Haskell types. A `Functor` (that is, an instance of the type class, as opposed to a functor in general) is a mapping from the **Hask** category (the category of Haskell types and functions) to **Hask** itself; that is, `C` and `D` are both **Hask** in that case. The Wikibook chapter mentions that in the section *Functors on Hask*. In your example, the `Maybe` type constructor provides the first part of the mapping by taking some type `a` (an object in **Hask**) to the type `Maybe a` (another object in **Hask**).

> I guess you could rephrase my question like this: Is there a `Functor` that does not have an obvious implementation of `pure`?

One example is the pair `Functor`, `(,) a`. `fmap` is easy to write -- `\f (x, y) -> (x, f y)` -- but `pure` and `(<*>)` require a `Monoid` constraint on `a`, as there would be no way of dealing with the extra `a` values otherwise. For more discussion and other examples, see [*Good examples of Not a Functor/Functor/Applicative/Monad?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7220436/2751851)

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that `Applicative` instance kind of becomes a stretch for `Either` (which I'd be perfectly fine with just having an instance for `Bifunctor`, but on the other hand using it as a Monad is convenient), and would (IMHO) be inappropriate for something like:

```
data ABC a = A a | B a | C a
```

Where all of A,B,C are "equally OK". Since there's no obvious choice for which should be used for `pure`, it shouldn't be provided at all. Having `fmap` is still perfectly fine, though.

Comment: Makes sense ... the arbitrariness in connection with implementing pure is deferred until someone implements Applicative (and at that point a choice must be made).

Comment: @ruben.moor When you've decided how you want to implement `<*>` in your Applicative, `pure` isn't arbitrary anymore: it's constrained by the applicative laws. Implementing a totally arbitrary `pure` as part of Functor, where you wouldn't really have to think about how pure interacts with anything else, could make it easy to accidentally write a `pure` that doesn't work for Applicative (or Monad).

Answer (score 2):

The category Hask has types as objects and functions as arrows, so the object mapping provided by the Functor instance must map types to types.

`fmap` maps the arrows i.e. maps functions `a -> b` to functions `f a -> f b` for the functor f. The Functor type constructor is the mapping for objects i.e. between types.

For example the `Maybe` type constructor maps a type `t` to the type `Maybe t` e.g. `String` to `Maybe String`.

In contrast, `pure` maps values of some underlying type to a value of the corresponding applicative type e.g. "abc" and (Just "abc") are both values of `String` and `Maybe String` respectively.

Comment: Would you agree that the Wikibook article confuses the category morphism with pure, where it says: maps any object A in C to F(A), in D ?

Comment: The wikibook article is correct. The `f` in `Functor f` maps objects in the category `Hask` to objects in the category `Hask`. Note that a Haskell `Functor` is strictly an endofunctor - its domain and codomain must both be `Hask`. Then, the function `fmap` maps morphism in Hask (functions of type `a -> b`) to morphisms in Hask, specifically to the morphism `f a -> f b`. In the article, the functor is given type `Hask ~> Hask`. But note that this arrow isn't the function arrow - the function arrow takes *types* to *types*, not categories to categories.

Comment: @user2407038 indeed, now I get it.