# Why must fmap map every element of a List?

Tags: haskell, functor, scalaz, category-theory, scala-cats

Having read the book [Learn you a Haskell For Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/), and the very helpful wiki book article [Haskell Category Theory](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory) which helped me overcome the common category mistake [of confusing category objects with the programming objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33441140/why-is-pure-only-required-for-applicative-and-not-already-for-functor), I still have the following question:

**Why must `fmap` map over every elements of a List?**

I like that it does, I just want to understand how this is justified category theoretically. ( or perhaps it is easier to justify using HoTT? )

In Scala notation, `List` is a functor that takes any type and maps that into an type from the set of all list types, eg it maps the type `Int` to the type `List[Int]` and it maps the functions on `Int` eg

- `Int.successor: Int => Int` to `Functor[List].fmap(successor) : List[Int] => List[Int]`
- `Int.toString: Int => String` to `Functor[List].fmap(toString): List[Int] => List[String]`

Now every instance of `List[X]` is a monoid with a [`empty` function](https://github.com/non/algebra/blob/ae69096581de077b1e6195eb0e4a4d6446f0001c/core/src/main/scala/algebra/Monoid.scala#L5) (`mempty` in Haskell) and [`combine` function](https://github.com/non/algebra/blob/ae69096581de077b1e6195eb0e4a4d6446f0001c/core/src/main/scala/algebra/Semigroup.scala#L9-L9) (`mappend` in Haskell). My guess is that one can use the fact that Lists are Monoids, to show that `map` has to map all elements of a list. My feeling here is that if one adds the [`pure` function from Applicative](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/051fb845d6219784de2fe231d8bfecfc1f880fb9/core/src/main/scala/cats/Applicative.scala#L16-L16), this gives us a list with just one element of some other type. e.g `Applicative[List[Int]].pure(1) == List(1)`. Since `map(succ)` on those elements gives us the singleton list with the next element, this covers all those subsets. Then I suppose the `combine` function on all those singletons gives us all the other elements of the lists. Somehow I suppose that constrains the way map has to work.

Another suggestive argument is that `map` has to map functions between lists. Since every element in a `List[Int]` is of type Int, and if one maps to `List[String]` one has to map every element of it, or one would not the right type.

So both of those arguments seem to point in the right direction. But I was wondering what was needed to get the rest of the way.

**Counterexample?**

Why is this not a counterexample map function?

```
def map[X,Y](f: X=>Y)(l: List[X]): List[Y] = l match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case head::tail=> List(f(head))
}
```

It seems to follow the rules

```
val l1 = List(3,2,1)
val l2 = List(2,10,100)

val plus2 = (x: Int) => x+ 2
val plus5 = (x: Int) => x+5

map(plus2)(List()) == List()
map(plus2)(l1) == List(5)
map(plus5)(l1) == List(8)

map(plus2 compose plus5)(l1) == List(10)
(map(plus2)_ compose map(plus5)_)(l1) == List(10)
```

Ahh. But it does not fit the id law.

```
def id[X](x: X): X = x

map(id[Int] _)(l1) == List(3)
id(l1) == List(3,2,1)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This relies on a theoretical result called "parametricity", first defined by Reynolds and then developed by Wadler (among others). Perhaps the most famous paper on this topic is ["Theorems for free!"](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/topics/parametricity.html) by Wadler.

The key idea is that from the polymorphic type of a function *only*, we can get some information about the semantics of the function. For instance:

```
foo :: a -> a
```

From this type alone, we can see that, if `foo` terminates, it is the identity function. Intuitively, `foo` can not distinguish between different `a`s since in Haskell we do not have e.g. Java's `instanceof` which can inspect the actual runtime type. Similarly,

```
bar :: a -> b -> a
```

must return the first argument. And `baz :: a -> a -> a` must return either the first or the second. And `quz :: a -> (a -> a) -> a` must apply some fixed number of times the function to the first argument. You probably get the idea now.

The general property which can be inferred from a type is quite complex, but luckily it can be computed [mechanically](http://www-ps.iai.uni-bonn.de/cgi-bin/free-theorems-webui.cgi). In category-theory, this is related to the notion of [natural transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation).

For the `map` type, we get the following scary property:

```
forall t1,t2 in TYPES, f :: t1 -> t2.
 forall t3,t4 in TYPES, g :: t3 -> t4.
  forall p :: t1 -> t3.
   forall q :: t2 -> t4.
    (forall x :: t1. g (p x) = q (f x))
    ==> (forall y :: [t1].
          map_{t3}_{t4} g (map2_{t1}_{t3} p y) =
          map2_{t2}_{t4} q (map_{t1}_{t2} f y))
```

Above, `map` is the well-known map function, while `map2` is any arbitrary function which has type `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`.

Now, further assume that `map2` satisfies the functor laws, in particular `map2 id = id`. We then can choose `p = id` and `t3 = t1`. We get

```
forall t1,t2 in TYPES, f :: t1 -> t2.
 forall t4 in TYPES, g :: t1 -> t4.
   forall q :: t2 -> t4.
    (forall x :: t1. g x = q (f x))
    ==> (forall y :: [t1].
          map_{t1}_{t4} g (map2_{t1}_{t1} id y) =
          map2_{t2}_{t4} q (map_{t1}_{t2} f y))
```

Applying the functor law on `map2`:

```
forall t1,t2 in TYPES, f :: t1 -> t2.
 forall t4 in TYPES, g :: t1 -> t4.
   forall q :: t2 -> t4.
    (forall x :: t1. g x = q (f x))
    ==> (forall y :: [t1].
          map_{t1}_{t4} g y =
          map2_{t2}_{t4} q (map_{t1}_{t2} f y))
```

Now, let's choose `t2 = t1` and `f = id`:

```
forall t1 in TYPES.
 forall t4 in TYPES, g :: t1 -> t4.
   forall q :: t1 -> t4.
    (forall x :: t1. g x = q x)
    ==> (forall y :: [t1].
          map_{t1}_{t4} g y =
          map2_{t1}_{t4} q (map_{t1}_{t1} id y))
```

By the functor law of `map`:

```
forall t1, t4 in TYPES.
   forall g :: t1 -> t4, q :: t1 -> t4.
    g = q
    ==> (forall y :: [t1].
          map_{t1}_{t4} g y =
          map2_{t1}_{t4} q y)
```

which means

```
forall t1, t4 in TYPES.
 forall g :: t1 -> t4.
    (forall y :: [t1].
          map_{t1}_{t4} g y =
          map2_{t1}_{t4} g y)
```

which means

```
forall t1, t4 in TYPES.
          map_{t1}_{t4} = map2_{t1}_{t4}
```

Summing up:

If `map2` is any function with polymorphic type `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`, and such that it satisfies the first functor law `map2 id = id`, then `map2` must be equivalent to the standard `map` function.

Also see a [related blog post by Edward Kmett](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/edwardk/snippets/fmap).

Note that in Scala the above holds only if you do not use `x.isInstanceOf[]`, and other reflection tools, which can break parametricity.

Comment: could `foo:: a -> a` not be the successor function? `succ:: Int => Int` is not the identity function. succ 1 == 2

Comment: I am having trouble following this for the moment, because I get stuck on the question in the previous comment. In any case you may want to check out how Theorems for Free fit in with HoTT. [Apparently it's not that easy](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/hott-cafe/ak301lhl9Qs/TLUDoah40pkJ) and may be false there...

Comment: @HenryStory : `succ` has the type `Int -> Int`, which is not the same as `a -> a`, that is, `forall a. a -> a`. The type of `succ` is more specific than `a -> a`, and `map succ` is well-typed, but according to `map`s type, `map` must work for all such functions, and thus cannot assume anything about them.

Comment: @HenryStory If Haskell allowed existention types, we could write `succ :: exists a. a -> a`. However, parametricity applies to types such as `forall a. a -> a`, i.e. functions that have to work on "all" arguments of the unknown type `a`.

Comment: @HenryStory I'd would neglect HoTT for this. HoTT is beautiful, but it's about dependent types (and higher homotopies), which Haskell lacks. I don't believe HoTT can help here (but I'd love to be proved wrong on this...)

Comment: Put another way, don't confuse (the syntactically illegal) `forall a . succ :: a -> a` (which say, "Give me a type, and I can provide a definition of `such` for that type) with `succ :: forall a . a -> a`, which says "Give me a definition of `succ`, and I can apply *that definition* to a value of any type."

Comment: Good thing I asked this question here. I don't think I would have found this proof by myself soon :-)