# Understanding differences between functors, applicative functors and monads?

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, applicative

I've gone over functors, applicative functors and monad in learnyouahaskell, however I'm struggling to understand the exact characteristics that differentiate these 3 language elements.

Does anyone have a simple example that show the differences of these concepts?

Comment: I think your problem is covered in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220436/good-examples-of-not-a-functor-functor-applicative-monad) question.