# What are the situations when you can/cannot have a Functor instances for a datatype?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functor, category-theory

Considering a type with kind * -> *, I'm trying to find rules and build intuition for when you can and when you cannot have Functor for this type.

So far the rules that I see are the following:

1. No `Functor` instance for the container types that have restrictions
   on the contained values.

Example: You cannot have a `Functor` instance for `Set` because `Ord` is needed for the contained value

2. No `Functor` instance for contravariant data types.

Example:

```
newtype Contra a = Contra (a -> Int)
```

Besides this, are there other situations?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7220436/477476

Comment: Why not formulate it constructively: what are the situations when you _can_ have a Functor instance? That's IMO always so much more useful to consider.

Comment: I suppose you could count types with the wrong kind, e.g. `newtype Fix f = Fix { unFix :: f (Fix f) }` has a kind `Fix :: (* -> *) -> *` whereas `Functor` requires a type constructor of kind `* -> *`, i.e. `Functor :: (* -> *) -> Constraint`. (`Fix` is, however, a functor in the general categorical sense, from the category of Haskell endofunctors to the category of Haskell types.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'm looking for some rules plus the intuition behind them. At some point I thought that you could have functors for any container, which is obviously wrong. So I have the feeling that you can have Functor instances for most of the containers except a few cases.

Comment: @cactus I've seen the linked question but I'm trying to identify other rules and build an intuition

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Wrong kind is definitely not suitable for Functor. I'll update the question to avoid discussions in this direction. As for your Fix type I don't understand it. Can you post a link with more info? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to your rules:

- Must be of kind `* -> *`
- No `Functor` instance for the container types that have restrictions on the contained values.
- No `Functor` instance for contravariant data types.

I would add a few:

- A natural extension of "not for contravariant types": no `Functor` instance for invariant data types. e.g. `data Iso a b = Iso (a -> b) (b -> a)`
- GADTs often cannot have a `Functor` instance. For example,

  ```
  data Foo a where
      Foo :: Foo Int
  ```

  Perhaps you would somehow want to lump this into the "only covariant" rule somehow (it's not clear to me what variance this even has), or the "unrestricted container types" rule somehow (GADTs introduce type equalities that are very constraint-like).

However, keep in mind that these rules apply to `Functor` *only*, not to functors in general. I expect any stupid type (of appropriate kind) you can cook up will be a functor on some suitable category closely related to Hask.

Comment: Can you explain with more details what you mean by "these rules apply to Functor only, not to functors in general."? Thanks!

Comment: @vidi Expanding on that might be another whole answer, and the level to write it at depends a lot on how comfortable you are with functors to begin with. But in short: you could imagine `class Functor' f where fmap' :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` with essentially the same class laws as `Functor` and which would admit an instance for `Set` even though `Functor` doesn't. And a suitably modified class with an essentially identical class law could be cooked up for most non-`Functor`s.

Comment: @vidi Or, to put it another way: the strictures of Haskell as a language already make it quite easy to satisfy the much more relaxed rules imposed by merely being a functor. Parametric polymorphism already stops you from writing most of the stupid stuff that the functor laws are designed to rule out.

Answer (score 5):

From the point of view of category theory, Haskell's type constructors of the kind `*->*` define a *mapping of objects* in the category Hask (it's a category modulo termination issues, which I'm going to conveniently ignore). A functor is a mapping of objects and, more importantly, a *mapping of morphisms*. In fact, it's primarily a mapping of morphisms--the mapping of objects is, in a way, a side effect of that. Objects are just the endpoints of morphisms. This mapping of morphisms must preserve composition and identity.

In Haskell, morphisms are functions, and the mapping of functions is implemented as `fmap`.

The fact that in Haskell we start with the mapping of objects is a little backwards. This works because the syntax of the language drastically limits the possibilities for defining the mapping of objects. Such mapping are very regular and, quite often, come equipped with canonical mappings of functions. For instance, algebraic data types are constructed using products and coproducts, which are functorial in nature (hence the possibility of `deriving Functor` automatically). Also, function types (categorical exponentials) are functorial in the second argument (and contravariant in the first). So, as long as we use the tools of the bicartesian closed category (products, coproducts, and exponentials), it's easy to construct functorial mappings of objects.

A functor must be defined for every object in a given category, so data types that are constrained by type classes (e.g., `Set` with the `Ord` constraint) are not `Functor`s in Hask, but they may be functors in a subcategory of Hask. (It's possible to define subcategories in Haskell together with their own functors.)

Answer (score 0):

There is `-XDerivingFunctor` extension in Haskell user guide. You can find full description [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#deriving-functor-instances). It has description of all cases when functor deriving can fail. This description has cases when algorithm checks for proper kind, etc. But I believe this list of constraints for algorithm is exhaustive.

For example, another case, when type has *kind* `* -> *` but cannot be instance of `Functor`:

> A data type’s last type variable is used in an -XExistentialQuantification constraint, or is refined in a GADT

Comment: According to the documentation, `DerivingFunctor` won't derive a functor instance for `newtype Wrong a = Wrong (Either a Int)`; but that doesn't mean `Wrong` *can't* be a `Functor`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yes, it's true. `DerivingFunctor` mechanism is more restrictive. I was just referring to official documentation where one can look for all cases. But this documentation should be read not blindly to not miss that case you mentioned in comment.