# Is `data PoE a = Empty | Pair a a` a monad?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

This question comes from this answer in
[example of a functor that is Applicative but not a Monad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49703783/412549):
It is claimed that the

```
data PoE a = Empty | Pair a a deriving (Functor,Eq)
```

cannot have a monad instance, but I fail to see that with:

```
instance Applicative PoE where
    pure x = Pair x x
    Pair f g <*> Pair x y = Pair (f x) (g y)
    _        <*> _        = Empty
instance Monad PoE where
    Empty    >>= _ = Empty
    Pair x y >>= f = case (f x, f y) of 
                       (Pair x' _,Pair _ y') -> Pair x' y'
                       _ -> Empty
```

The actual reason why I believe this to be a monad is that it is isomorphic to `Maybe (Pair a)` with `Pair a = P a a`. They are both monads, both traversables so their composition should form a monad, too. [Oh, I just found out not always](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42284879/2751851).

Which counter-example failes which monad law? (and how to find that out systematically?)

---

*edit:* I did not expect such an interest in this question. Now I have to make up my mind if I accept the best example or the best answer to the "systematically" part.

Meanwhile, I want to visualize how `join` works for the simpler `Pair a = P a a`:

```
                   P
          ________/ \________
         /                   \
        P                     P
       / \                   / \
      1   2                 3   4
```

it always take the outer path, yielding `P 1 4`, more commonly known as a diagonal in a matrix representation. For monad associativy I need three dimensions, a tree visualization works better. Taken from chi's answer, this is the failing example for join, and how I can comprehend it.

```
                  Pair
          _________/\_________
         /                    \
       Pair                   Pair
        /\                     /\
       /  \                   /  \
    Pair  Empty           Empty  Pair
     /\                           /\
    1  2                         3  4
```

Now you do the `join . fmap join` by collapsing the lower levels first, for `join . join` collapse from the root.

Comment: I'm sure you already noticed this, but the answerer did reply to your comment on that post that you linked. I personally am not able to construct a counterexample fitting his description at a glance, but I wanted to make you aware of his comment.

Comment: What makes an applicative a Monad is the ability to squash it (using join) and so transform a pair of pair to a pair. You can't do it without losing some elements (going from 4 to 2) as you do in your example. That's will break the laws.  For example `Pair (Pair 1 2) Empty >>= return ` returns Empty. That s not good .

Comment: @mb14 I ran it in my head and I don't get `Empty`.

Comment: I ran it in [TIO](https://tio.run/##dU9dT4MwFH3vrzjJHqAGTPRxcSREcTHxY0b3TBpWoGErWIqDqL8dS4GZGL0PTc@993zcnNUF3@/7/sNf4D58XG/DdYQbrsQ7v21kokuFhf9FiDhUpdJ45bU@f25EUlznPCkI2THNsCkjMKwQHSrd4RMbJpRpMOwGISEzuJOYF715L3l5pEZR1prJhCOsqr1ImDaWVumYc8UJTFWN4miNsBVs0dquBSkyXJ0F86Sbl9wULYWboaN2OcZUw/IJTFF/MjyUku1@uY/XmAqClaHOnFOEwXUYpWaUsJpbb8/AjqJMQfB3uSPZQezZX4zOofDnUxwD/6PGw9qYghyYkFgucfcEl45ohUoJqSeH8b3AJZ0uGbIqrhslad9/Aw) and I don't get `Empty`

Comment: @mb14 Losing elements isn't in itself a problem -- `(>>=)` and `join` don't have to preserve all information. `data Pair a = P a a` is indeed a monad, as the OP points out.

Comment: @duplode even though my example didn't work, the fact you lose elements is at the heart of the failure of the join law explained on other post. So in a way losing elements is a problem. In fact I think is the significance of the functor `fmap id = id` law (not lose, shuffle or duplicate elements).

Comment: I meant `>>= id`

Comment: @mb14 (1) To me, it seems it is more a question of losing effects than of losing elements, though I still have to make it clearer (to myself, even) what I mean with "losing effects". (2) "I meant `>>= id`" -- I assume you mean your example was actually `Pair (Pair 1 2) Empty >>= id = Empty`?

Comment: Interesting that very similar type is actually a monad: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43684258/how-to-define-a-monad-instance-to-types-with-mutiple-values

Comment: @Shersh  interesting indeed, however the main difference is the possibily to have only one element or two, which allows to not drop or have to duplicate things.

Comment: @duplode (1) https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor#Functor_Laws (2) yes :-)

Comment: @mb14 I don't think the functor laws are applicable here, unless we are talking about the functor laws for `(=<<)`, which amount to two of the monad laws -- `(return =<<) = id` and `((g <=< f) =<<) = (g =<<) . (f =<<)`. It is also worth noting that the identitly law implies the composition law for `fmap`, but not for `(=<<)`. There may well be an interesting way to look at this situation in those terms.

Comment: @duplode Monad being a Functor must follow the Functor laws. It is likely that Functor laws are including in Monad Laws and therefore don't need to be proven (as they can be proven from the monad laws and the definition of `fmap` for a Monad). However, making a Functor law fails should also prove that the Monad laws fails.

Comment: @mb14 The `Functor` laws don't fail for `PoE`: `fmap f = \case { Empty -> Empty; Pair x y -> Pair (f x) (f y) }` is perfectly legal. When I talk of "the functor laws for `(=<<)`", [I mean a different functor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39955475/2751851), one which is not a `Functor` (that is, not an endofunctor in **Hask**).

Comment: @duplode Fair enough, anyway, it is the losse in `(Pair x' _) -> ...` which makes it an invalid Monad , even though I agree it's a valid Functor.

Comment: @mb14 I would say the problem doesn't lie there, but rather with `Empty`. Without `Empty`, that becomes a lawful `(>>=)`.

Comment: @Shersh In the terms of my [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49743437/2751851), that instance is lawful because it isn't actually taking the diagonal. (I suspect the only variable length list-like type in which taking the diagonal gives a lawful monad is `Maybe` -- in that case, there simply aren't enough ways to mess with the diagonals in order to get an associativity failure.)

Comment: Not sure I understand this intuition about "taking the diagonal" or "losing effects". Any functor of the form `Either (a, a, a) (a, a, a, a, a)`, or more generally, a sum of any number of products of any number of `a`'s, is a lawful monad, and sometimes in more than one way.  How can this be explained heuristically using "diagonals" or "losing information"?

Comment: If `m` is a monad then `Either a (m a)` is a monad and also `m (Either c (w, a))` is a monad for any constant type `c` and any monoid type `w` (we can take `w = ()` or `c = Void` here). If `m1` and `m2` are monads then `(m1 a, m2 a)` is a monad. Using these constructions and starting with the identity monad, lots of polynomial monads can be constructed. It is not clear how to detect which polynomial functors are not monads. I'm having trouble coming with explicit counterexamples other than `Maybe (a, a)`, `Maybe (a, a, a)` and so on.

Comment: Another example of a polynomial functor that cannot be obtained using the above constructions is `data P a = Empty | One a | Three a a a`. I conjecture that it is not a monad, but I do not know how to prove in general that these constructions are the only ones yielding lawful polynomial monads.

Comment: @Franky the reason your question generated interest is, I believe, because nobody really knows how to recognize a monad reliably without a lot of tedious calculations. The existing literature and tutorials never talk about this, so even simple types like `Either c (a, a)` give us a pause. What we have seen is that QuickCheck will often, but not always, detect a problem. So using QuickCheck is not an ideal recipe. Proving the laws symbolically would require a proof assistant and is also not a great experience.

Comment: @winitzki On diagonals: taking the diagonal (first element from the first "list", second element from the second "list", etc.) is one of the plausible ways to attempt writing `join` for a list-like type such as the ones we are discussing here. Your instance for `Either (a, a, a) (a, a, a, a, a)` does not amount to taking the diagonal. I agree with your suggestion that it is a good idea to think about an intuitive way of describing it.

Comment: @winitzki I have just figured out how to explain `Either a (a,a...a)` being a monad in terms of diagonals: if you find a `Left x` while taking the diagonal of a `Right (m1,m2...mn)`, replicate it to get the `(a,a...a)` tuple you need. This generalises to `Monad m => Either a (m a)`: you just have to replace "replicate" with "use `pure`".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently, it is not a monad. One of the monad "`join`" laws is

```
join . join = join . fmap join
```

Hence, according to the law above, these two outputs should be equal, but they are not.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let x = Pair (Pair (Pair 1 2) Empty) (Pair Empty (Pair 7 8))
  print (join . join $ x)
  -- output: Pair 1 8
  print (join . fmap join $ x)
  -- output: Empty
```

The problem is that

```
join x      = Pair (Pair 1 2) (Pair 7 8)
fmap join x = Pair Empty Empty
```

Performing an additional `join` on those does not make them equal.

> how to find that out systematically?

`join . join` has type `m (m (m a)) -> m (m a)`, so I started with a triple-nested `Pair`-of-`Pair`-of-`Pair`, using numbers `1..8`. That worked fine. Then, I tried to insert some `Empty` inside, and quickly found the counterexample above.

This approach was possible since a `m (m (m Int))` only contains a finite amount of integers inside, and we only have constructors `Pair` and `Empty` to try.

For these checks, I find the `join` law easier to test than, say, associativity of `>>=`.

Comment: Well played. You can make the `Empty` disappear by positioning them carefully. Good answer!

Comment: Good solution; I wrote a Scala version of it:
https://gist.github.com/vpatryshev/49fec9fc9a49fe45d36234db5af81a03

Answer (score 11):

QuickCheck immediately finds a counterexample to associativity.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

import Test.QuickCheck

data PoE a = Empty | Pair a a deriving (Functor,Eq, Show)

instance Applicative PoE where
    pure x = Pair x x
    Pair f g <*> Pair x y = Pair (f x) (g y)
    _        <*> _        = Empty
instance Monad PoE where
    Empty    >>= _ = Empty
    Pair x y >>= f = case (f x, f y) of 
                       (Pair x' _,Pair _ y') -> Pair x' y'
                       _ -> Empty

instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (PoE a) where
  arbitrary = oneof [pure Empty, Pair <$> arbitrary <*> arbitrary]

prop_assoc :: PoE Bool -> (Bool -> PoE Bool) -> (Bool -> PoE Bool) -> Property
prop_assoc m k h =
  ((m >>= k) >>= h) === (m >>= (\a -> k a >>= h))

main = do
  quickCheck $ \m (Fn k) (Fn h) -> prop_assoc m k h
```

Output:

```
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 35 tests and 3 shrinks):    
Pair True False
{False->Pair False False, True->Pair False True, _->Empty}
{False->Pair False True, _->Empty}
Pair False True /= Empty
```

Comment: It's funny, I used `Bool` and no counterexample was found; I thought maybe the laws held just for bool because of some anomaly. But I guess it's just the imperfection of randomness..

Answer (score 6):

Since you are interested in how to do it systematically, here's how I found a counterexample with quickcheck:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

import Control.Monad ((>=>))
import Test.QuickCheck

-- <your code>
```

Defining an arbitrary instance to generate random `PoE`s.

```
instance (Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (PoE a) where
    arbitrary = do
      emptyq <- arbitrary
      if emptyq
        then return Empty
        else Pair <$> arbitrary <*> arbitrary
```

And tests for the monad laws:

```
prop_right_id m = (m >>= return) == m
    where
    _types = (m :: PoE Int)

prop_left_id fun x = (return x >>= f) == f x
    where
    _types = fun :: Fun Int (PoE Int)
    f = applyFun fun

prop_assoc fun gun hun x = (f >=> (g >=> h)) x == ((f >=> g) >=> h) x
    where
    _types = (fun :: Fun Int (PoE Int),
              gun :: Fun Int (PoE Int),
              hun :: Fun Int (PoE Int),
              x :: Int)
    f = applyFun fun
    g = applyFun gun
    h = applyFun hun
```

I don't get any failures for the identity laws, but `prop_assoc` does generate a counterexample:

```
ghci> quickCheck prop_assoc
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 7 tests and 36 shrinks):
{6->Pair 1 (-1), _->Empty}
{-1->Pair (-3) (-4), 1->Pair (-1) (-2), _->Empty}
{-3->Empty, _->Pair (-2) (-4)}
6
```

Not that it's terribly helpful for understanding *why* the failure occurs, it does give you a place to start.  If we look carefully, we see that we are passing `(-3)` and `(-2)` to the third function; `(-3)` maps to `Empty` and `(-2)` maps to a `Pair`, so we can't defer to the laws of either of the two monads `PoE` is composed of.

Answer (score 6):

This kind of potential `Monad` instance can be concisely described as "taking the diagonal". It is easier to see why if we use the `join` presentation. Here is `join` for the `Pair` type you mention:

```
join (P (P a00 a11) (P a10 a11)) = P a00 a11
```

Taking the diagonal, however, is only guaranteed to give a lawful `join` for fixed length (or infinite) lists. That's because of the associativity law:

```
join . join = join . fmap join
```

If the n-th list in a list of lists doesn't have an n-th element, it will lead to the diagonal being trimmed: it will end before its n-th element. `join . join` takes the outer diagonal (of a list of lists *of lists*) first, while `join . fmap join` takes the inner diagonals first. It may be possible for an insufficiently long innermost list which is not in the outer diagonal to trim `join . fmap join`, but it can't possibly affect `join . join`. (This would be easier to show with a picture instead of words.)

Your `PoE` is a list-like type that doesn't have fixed length (the length is either zero or two). It turns out that taking its diagonal doesn't give us a monad, as the potential issue discussed above actually gets in the way (as illustrated in [chi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49742857/2751851)).

Additional notes:

- This is precisely the reason [`ZipList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList) is not a monad: the zippy behaviour amounts to taking the diagonal.
- Infinite lists are isomorphic to functions from the naturals, and fixed length lists are isomorphic to functions from the naturals up to an appropriate value. This means you can get a `Monad` instance for them out of the instance for functions -- and the instance you get, again, amounts to taking the diagonal.
- [Once upon a time I got confused about this exact issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/5x4yka/deprecate_foldable_for_either/dehoey7/).

Answer (score 4):

(Posting this as a separate answer, as it has little overlap with my other one.)

> The actual reason why I believe this to be a monad is that it is isomorphic to `Maybe (Pair a)` with `Pair a = P a a`. They are both monads, both traversables so their composition should form a monad, too. [Oh, I just found out not always](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42284879/2751851).

The conditions for the composition of monads `m`-over-`n` with `n` traversable are:

```
-- Using TypeApplications notation to make the layers easier to track.
sequenceA @n @m . pure @n = fmap @m (pure @n)
sequenceA @n @m . fmap @n (join @m)
    = join @m . fmap @m (sequenceA @n @m) . sequenceA @n @m
sequenceA @n @m . join @n
    = fmap @m (join @n) . sequenceA @n @m . fmap @n (sequenceA @n @m)
```

(There is also `sequenceA @n @m . fmap @n (pure @m) = pure @m`, but that always holds.)

In our case, we have `m ~ Maybe` and `n ~ Pair`. The relevant method definitions for `Pair` would be:

```
fmap f (P x y) = P (f x) (f y)
pure x = P x x
P f g <*> P x y = P (f x) (g y)
join (P (P a00 a01) (P a10 a11)) = P a00 a11 -- Let's pretend join is a method.
sequenceA (P x y) = P <$> x <*> y
```

Let's check the third property:

```
sequenceA @n @m . join @n
    = fmap @m (join @n) . sequenceA @n @m . fmap @n (sequenceA @n @m)

-- LHS
sequenceA . join $ P (P a00 a01) (P a10 a11)
sequenceA $ P a00 a11
P <$> a00 <*> a11 -- Maybe (Pair a)

-- RHS
fmap join . sequenceA . fmap sequenceA $ P (P a00 a01) (P a10 a11)
fmap join . sequenceA $ P (P <$> a00 <*> a01) (P <$> a10 <*> a11)
fmap join $ P <$> (P <$> a00 <*> a01) <*> (P <$> a10 <*> a11)
fmap join $ (\x y z w -> P (P x y) (P z w)) <$> a00 <*> a01 <*> a10 <*> a11
(\x _ _ w -> P x w) <$> a00 <*> a01 <*> a10 <*> a11 -- Maybe (Pair a)
```

These are clearly not the same: while any `a` values will be drawn exclusively from `a00` and `a11`, the effects of `a01` and `a10` are ignored in the left-hand side, but not in the right-hand side (in other words, if `a01` or `a10` are `Nothing`, the RHS will be `Nothing`, but the LHS won't necessarily be so). The LHS corresponds exactly to the vanishing `Empty` in [chi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49742857/2751851), and the RHS corresponds to the inner diagonal trimming described in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49743437/2751851).

---

P.S.: I forgot to show that the would-be instance we are talking about here is the same one being discussed in the question:

```
join' ::  m (n (m (n a))) -> m (n a)
join' = fmap @m (join @n) . join @m . fmap @m (sequenceA @n @m)
```

With `m ~ Maybe` and `n ~ Pair`, we have:

```
join' :: Maybe (Pair (Maybe (Pair a))) -> Maybe (Pair a)
join' = fmap @Maybe (join @Pair) . join @Maybe . fmap @Maybe (sequenceA @Pair @Maybe)
```

`join @Maybe . fmap @Maybe (sequenceA @Pair @Maybe)` means the `join'` will result in `Nothing` unless there are no `Nothing`s anywhere:

```
join' = \case
    Just (P (Just (P a00 a01)) (Just (P a10 a11))) -> _
    _ -> Nothing
```

Working out the non-`Nothing` case is straightforward:

```
fmap join . join . fmap sequenceA $ Just (P (Just (P a00 a01)) (Just (P a10 a11)))
fmap join . join $ Just (Just (P (P a00 a01) (P a10 a11)))
fmap join $ Just (P (P a00 a01) (P a10 a11))
Just (P a00 a11)
```

Therefore...

```
join' = \case
    Just (P (Just (P a00 _)) (Just (P _ a11))) -> Just (P a00 a11)
    _ -> Nothing
```

... which is essentially the same as:

```
join = \case
    Pair (Pair a00 _) (Pair _ a11) -> Pair (a00 a11)
    _ -> Empty
```