# Why is `((,) r)` a Functor that is NOT an Applicative?

Tags: haskell, applicative, category-theory

From [functors that are not applicatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220436/good-examples-of-not-a-functor-functor-applicative-monad):

> **A type constructor which is a Functor but not an Applicative.** A simple example is a pair:
>
> ```
> instance Functor ((,) r) where
>     fmap f (x,y) = (x, f y)
> ```
>
> But there is no way how to define its `Applicative` instance without imposing additional restrictions on `r`. In particular, there is no way how to define `pure :: a -> (r, a)` for an arbitrary `r`.

**Question 1:** Why is this so? Here is how `pure` could work with functions `f` of type `a -> b`:

```
(pure f) (pure x, pure y) = (pure x, pure f y)
```

From there, the definition of `pure :: a -> (r, a)` could depend on what `r` is. For example, if `r` is `Integer`, then you could define

```
pure x = (0 :: Integer, x)
```

in your instance declaration. So what is the issue?

**Question 2:** Can we say in general that if `F` is a functor, then `<*>` can always be defined, but `pure` might not always be defined?

Answer (score 11):

Suppose we have

```
pure :: forall r a. a -> (r, a)
```

then, in particular, we have

```
magic :: forall r. r
magic = fst (pure ())
```

Now, we can specialise the type variable `r` to get

```
magic :: Void
```

where `Void` is the datatype with no constructors, which means

```
magic = undefined
```

but as type variables (and the types which specialise them) play no run time role, that means `magic` is *always* undefined.

We've discovered that `((,) r)` can be `Applicative` only for *inhabited* `r`. And there's more. With any such instance, we can write

```
munge :: r -> r -> r
munge r0 r1 = fst ( pure (\ _ _ -> ()) <*> (r0, ()) <*> (r1, ()) )
```

to define a binary operator on `r`. The `Applicative` laws tell us effectively that `munge` must be an associative operator that absorbs `magic` on either side.

That's to say there *is* a sensible instance

```
instance Monoid r => Applicative ((,) r) where
  pure a              = (mempty, a)
  (r0, f) <*> (r1, s) = (mappend r0 r1, f s)
```

(exactly what you get when you take `pure=return; (<*>)=ap` from the `Monad (Writer r)`).

Of course, some pedants would argue that it is legal (if unhelpful) to define

```
instance Monoid r where
  mempty = undefined
  mappend _ _ = undefined
  -- Monoid laws clearly hold
```

but I would argue that any sensible type class instance should contribute nontrivially to the defined fragment of the language.

Comment: Interestingly, it works the other way around as well. `instance Applicative ((,) r) => Monoid r`.

Answer (score 8):

**Answer 1:**

> ```
> (pure f) (pure x, pure y) = (pure x, pure f y)
> ```

I don't understand what you mean by this line. It looks like nonsense: `pure f` would be a pair, and you can't apply a pair as if it were a function.

> From there, the definition of `pure :: a -> (r, a)` could depend on what `r` is.

That is exactly the problem. `r` is fully general; the instance declaration says `((,) r)` is a Functor *for all types `r`*. That means you have to somehow implement a single `pure :: a -> (r, a)` that works with any type `r` that a caller might choose. This is impossible because there is no way to conjure up an arbitrary `r` from thin air.

Or as your quote says:

> > In particular, there is no way how to define `pure :: a -> (r, a)` for an arbitrary `r`.

If you try to do something like

```
pure x = (0 :: Integer, x)
```

you get an error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘r’ with actual type ‘Integer’
  ‘r’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the instance declaration
      at ...
```

---

**Answer 2:**

What would `<*>` look like for pairs? It would be a function like

```
(<*>) :: (r, a -> b) -> (r, a) -> (r, b)
(r1, f) (r2, x) = (???, f x)
```

But what do you do with the `???` part? You have to put a value of `r` there, and fortunately you have some of those available (`r1`, `r2`). The problem is that (for arbitrary `r`) there is no general way to combine two values, so you have to pick one of them.

That's where you run into trouble with the laws:

```
pure id <*> v = v
```

This law says we have to pick `r2` to preserve `v`.

```
u <*> pure y = pure ($ y) <*> u
```

Since we have to pick `r2` in `<*>`, the right-hand side of this law says the result will contain the `r` part of `u`. But that clashes with the left-hand side, which says that we get whatever `r` was returned by `pure y`. (`u` is a completely arbitrary pair so there's no way a fixed value returned by `pure` is always going to match it.)

So we have a contradiction, meaning we can't even define `<*>` for `((,) r)`. Therefore the answer to your second question is "no".

---

That said, there is a standard `Applicative` instance for pairs but it requires `r` to be a `Monoid`:

```
instance (Monoid r) => Applicative ((,) r) where
    pure x = (mempty, x)
    (r1, f) (r2, x) = (mappend r1 r2, f x)
```

Comment: For Answer 2, I think the type would be `(<*>) :: (r -> r, a -> b) -> (r, a) -> (r, b)`. This would then force the value of `r -> r` to be `id`. You could then say `(r1, f) (r2, x) = (r1 r2, f x)`, or `(r1, f) (r2, x) = (r2, f x)`.

Comment: @George That's not a valid specialisation of `(<*>)`, as `(r -> r, a -> b)` does not involve the same `Functor` -- there, you have `((,) (r -> r))` rather than `((,) r)`.