# In functional programming terms, what do you call something with an orElse or other fallback method?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, partialfunction

Using scala for reference, we see a fallback behavior (`orElse`) in several places such as `PartialFunction`, `Option`, and cats `EitherOps`.

This feels similar to but not the same as the flattening behavior of a monad. Is there a functional programming term for things that exhibit this behavior?

Edit:
Some good answers so far, digging around more in cats, I've found

```
Semigroup[Option[String]].combine(None, Some("b"))
res0: Option[String] = Some(b)

Semigroup[Option[String]].combine(Some("a"), Some("b"))
res1: Option[String] = Some(ab)

SemigroupK[Option].combineK(None, Some("b"))
res2: Option[String] = Some(b)

SemigroupK[Option].combineK(Some("a"), Some("b"))
res3: Option[String] = Some(a)

SemigroupK[List].combineK(List("a"), List("b"))
res4: List[String] = List(a, b)

Alternative[List].unite(List(None, Some("a"), Some("b")))
res4: List[String] = List(a, b)
```

So I see now that the scalaz `Alt` and haskell `Alternative` are not quite the same as the cats `Alternative`. The more interesting thing is the [`SemigroupK`](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/semigroupk.html) (called `Plus` in scalaz according to the cats documentation).
So could we say this behavior is exhibited by a type for which you cannot define a semigroup without also having a semigroup for its inner type (because then we might say the scalaz `Alt` and haskell `Alternative` are semigroups for such kinds)?

Comment: Not "functional programming", but 'coalesce' comes to mind - albeit it often shows up as more specific case (eg. with null included in the domain) as `??` or `COALESCE(..)`. Someone will probably answer in terms of a Y combinators.. >_<

Comment: @user2864740 that's a good point, maybe we're looking for something like a 'monad coalescing operator'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A decent chunk of Scala is inspired by similar concepts in Haskell. In this particular case, `orElse` is pretty close to the "alternative" operator `<|>` in the [`Alternative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#g:2) typeclass.

In Haskell, an `Applicative` is a `Functor` (read: it contains things and has some way of interacting with those things) which has some meaningful monoidal way of "combining" those things: `<*>`. We can think of `<*>` as being somewhat similar (although not identical) to Scala's `andThen`, in that it takes two "successful" computations and sequences them. Under this analogy, an `Alternative` is an `Applicative` that provides a way to "recover" from failure, so `<|>` is more or less Scala's `orElse`.

Since you mentioned monads, `Applicative` is a weakening of `Monad`, in the sense that every `Monad` is an `Applicative` but not every `Applicative` is necessarily `Monad`. For example, multidimensional arrays can [easily](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7220548/2288659) be made into `Applicative` but cannot be made `Monad`.

So, to summarize, I believe the term you're looking for is "applicative functor with alternative capabilities", codified in Haskell by the `Alternative` typeclass. If you want to sound terribly arrogant, we can call it by its mathematically rigorous name: a strong lax monoidal functor backed by an additional monoidal structure. But that's just if we're showing off.

Answer (score 1):

There is `Alt`:

https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Alt.scala

Basically, `orElse` becomes `alt`:

`def alt[A](a1: =>F[A], a2: =>F[A]): F[A]`.