# Good examples of not a Contravariant/Contravariant/Divisible/Decidable?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functor, contravariant

[The `Contravariant` family of typeclasses](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.5.1/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant-Divisible.html) represents standard and fundamental abstractions in the Haskell ecosystem:

```
class Contravariant f where
    contramap :: (a -> b) -> f b -> f a

class Contravariant f => Divisible f where
    conquer :: f a
    divide  :: (a -> (b, c)) -> f b -> f c -> f a

class Divisible f => Decidable f where
    lose   :: (a -> Void) -> f a
    choose :: (a -> Either b c) -> f b -> f c -> f a
```

However, it's not that easy to understand the concepts behind these typeclasses. I think it would help to understand these typeclasses better if you could see some counterexamples for them. So, in the spirit of [*Good examples of Not a Functor/Functor/Applicative/Monad?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220436/good-examples-of-not-a-functor-functor-applicative-monad), I'm looking for contrasting examples of data types which satisfy the following requirements:

- A type constructor which is not a `Contravariant`?
- A type constructor which is a `Contravariant`, but not `Divisible`?
- A type constructor which is a `Divisible`, but is not a `Decidable`?
- A type constructor which is a `Decidable`?

Comment: Note that most (i.e. all 'nontrivial') functors are not contravariant.

Comment: @AJFarmar Yeah, it's not that difficult to come up with the example of a data type which is not a `Contravariant`, but this also not the most interesting part of the question :)

Comment: `newtype C a = C (a -> Int)` is contravariant.

Comment: Decidable is actually the dual of Alternative, so perhaps in the spirit of the original question then Comonad should be included in our inquisition of hierarchy?

Comment: I really wish `Divisible` had a superclass with `divide` but not `conquer`, dual to `Apply`.

Comment: This question [is being discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385338/2751851).

Comment: @duplode Interesting. My question received 4 downvotes today... English is not my native language, so if something can be improved in terms of wording to make the statement or question clear, I'm happy to accept any useful suggestions! But I don't think that the question should be closed.

Comment: Potential close voters: this question should not be closed, for the reasons discussed [in my Meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385341/2751851).

Comment: @Shersh "But I don't think that the question should be closed" -- Nor do I. Those votes, I believe, are mostly an artefact of the SO review system, which sometimes tricks people into developing strong opinions about questions they probably should refrain from passing judgement on.

Comment: @moonGoose The issue with including `Comonad` here is that it is not a subclass of `Divisible`. Its relationship with `Monad` is not the same as the one between `Divisible` and `Alternative`. (In a cursory way: (1a) A `Monad` is a monad in **Hask**; (1b) A `Comonad` is a monad in the dual category **Hask^op**, which we encode within **Hask** by flipping some arrows; (2a) An `Applicative` is a monoidal endofunctor in **Hask**; (2b) A `Divisible` is a monoidal functor from **Hask^op** to **Hask**, which we encode within **Hask** by flipping some arrows, but not quite in the same way.)

Answer (score 7):

(partial answer)

## Not contravariant

```
newtype F a = K (Bool -> a)
```

is not contravariant (it is, however, a covariant functor).

## Contravariant, but not divisible

```
newtype F a = F { runF :: a -> Void }
```

is contravariant but it can not be `Divisible` since otherwise

```
runF (conquer :: F ()) () :: Void
```

## A note on "divisible but non decidable"

I don't have a reasonable example for a divisible which is not decidable. We can observe that such a counterexample must be such because it violates the laws, and not just the type signature. Indeed, if `Divisible F` holds,

```
instance Decidable F where
    lose _ = conquer
    choose _ _ _ = conquer
```

satisfies the type signatures of the methods.

In libraries we find `Const m` as a divisible, when `m` is a monoid.

```
instance Monoid m => Divisible (Const m) where
  divide _ (Const a) (Const b) = Const (mappend a b)
  conquer = Const mempty
```

Perhaps this can not be a lawful `Decidable`? (I'm unsure, it seems to satisfy the `Decidable` laws, but there's no `Decidable (Const m)` instance in the libraries.)

## Decidable

Taken from the libraries:

```
newtype Predicate a = Predicate (a -> Bool)

instance Divisible Predicate where
  divide f (Predicate g) (Predicate h) = Predicate $ \a -> case f a of
    (b, c) -> g b && h c
  conquer = Predicate $ const True

instance Decidable Predicate where
  lose f = Predicate $ \a -> absurd (f a)
  choose f (Predicate g) (Predicate h) = Predicate $ either g h . f
```

Comment: What *are* the laws for `Divisible`? The documentation only mentions that `lose` should be an identity for `choose` (what does this mean, exactly, given the extra function arguments?); should there also be some analog of associativity?

Comment: @DanielWagner http://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.5.1/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant-Divisible.html#g:4 has some more laws

Comment: I don't think `Identity` can be an instance of `Contravariant`

Comment: @Carl I don't know what I was thinking. Thanks.

Comment: I like your examples! @user11228628 has detailed explanation on why `Const` cannot be `Decidable`. I think the documentation for the `contravariant` package can benefit a lot from these examples :)

Answer (score 6):

*(partial derivative answer?)*

I belive @chi is correct [when they hypothesize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56129941/2751851) that `Const m` can't be a lawful `Decidable` for all `Monoid`s `m`, but I'm basing that off of some speculation about the `Decidable` laws.

In [the docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.5.1/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant-Divisible.html#g:4), we get this tantalizing hint at a `Decidable` law:

> In addition, we expect the same kind of distributive law as is satisfied by the usual covariant Alternative, w.r.t Applicative, which should be fully formulated and added here at some point!

What sort of distributive relationship should `Decidable` and `Divisible` have with each other? Well, `Divisible` has `chosen`, which builds a product-accepting thing out of element-accepting things, and `Decidable` has `divided`, which builds a sum-accepting thing out of element-accepting things. Since products distribute over sums, perhaps the law we're seeking relates `f (a, Either b c)` to `f (Either (a, b) (a, c))`, values of which can be constructed via `` a `divided` (b `chosen` c) `` and `` (a `divided` b) `chosen` (a `divided` c) ``, respectively.

So I'll hypothesize that the missing `Decidable` law is something along the lines of

```
a `divided` (b `chosen` c) = contramap f ((a `divided` b) `chosen` (a `divided` c))
  where f (x, y) = bimap ((,) x) ((,) x) y
```

which is indeed satisfied for `Predicate`, `Equivalence`, and `Op` (the three `Decidable` instances I've taken the time to check, so far).

Now I believe the only instance you can have for `instance Monoid m => Decidable (Const m)` uses `mempty` for `lose` and `mappend` for `choose`; any other choices and then `lose` is no longer an identity for `choose`. This means that the above distributive law simplifies to

```
a `mappend` (b `mappend` c) = (a `mappend` b) `mappend` (a `mappend` c)
```

which is <strike>clearly bogus</strike> not true in an arbitrary `Monoid` (though, as Sjoerd Visscher observes, is true in some `Monoid`s—so `Const m` could still be a lawful `Decidable` if `m` is a distributive monoid).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Now it really makes sense why `Const` cannot be Decidable.

Comment: Const can be Decidable, just not for any monoid, but only for those that satisfy that law, ie left distributive monoids.