# Could you write a type function to invert a constraint?

Tags: haskell, data-kinds, constraint-kinds

Is it possible to write a type function that would take a constraint like Show and return one that constrains the RHS to types that are *not* an instance of Show?

The signature would be something like

```
type family Invert (c :: * -> Constraint) :: * -> Constraint
```

Comment: The answer is almost certainly "no".  Can you explain what it is you're trying to use this for?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/fun-type-functions/ shows a way to get a type-level predicate telling whether some type is a member of some class. By the time you've waded through that, you'll agree with "almost certainly 'no'". Consider the general problem: some type is a member of class `D` just in case it's _not_ a member of `C`. It's a member of `C` just in case it's not a member of `D`. (Of course it won't be as simple as that: there'll be a chain of inter-dependent class constraints.) The base problem is that constructivist logic can't use the law of excluded middle.

Comment: BTW this is a Haskell FAQ.

Comment: To support incremental compilation, GHC can never be sure that a given instance does _not_ exist. Checking that negative constraint would require inspecting all the modules, breaking incremental compilation.

Comment: I'd also remark that the inability to negate constraints relates to a rather deep mathematical idiom, that of [constructive logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic). It turns out it's often a really good idea to avoid classical binary _true or false_ thinking.

Answer (score 10):

No. It is a design principle of the language that you are *never* allowed to do this. The rule is if a program is valid, adding more `instance`s should not break it. This is the open-world assumption. Your desired constraint is a pretty direct violation:

```
data A = A
f :: Invert Show a => a -> [a]
f x = [x]
test :: [A]
test = f A
```

Would work, but adding

```
instance Show A
```

would break it. Therefore, the original program should never have been valid in the first place, and therefore `Invert` cannot exist.

Answer (score 3):

As HTNW answered, it is in general not supposed to be possible to assert that a type is not an instance of a class. However, it is certainly possible to assert *for a concrete type* that it's never supposed to be possible to have an instance of some class for it. An ad-hoc way would be this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, KindSignatures, AllowAmbiguousTypes
           , MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}

import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

class Non (c :: * -> Constraint) (t :: *) where
  nonAbsurd :: c t => r
```

But this is unsafe – the only way to write an instance is, like,

```
instance Non Show (String->Bool) where
  nonAbsurd = undefined
```

but then somebody else could come up with a bogus `instance Show (String->Bool)` and would then be able to use your `nonAbsurd` for proving the [moon is made out of green cheese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220436/good-examples-of-not-a-functor-functor-applicative-monad/7227048#7227048).

A better option to make an instance impossible is to “block” it: write that instance yourself “pre-emptively”, but in such a way that it's a type error to actually invoke it.

```
import Data.Constraint.Trivial -- from trivial-constraint

instance Impossible0 => Show (String->Bool) where
  show = nope
```

Now if anybody tries to add that instance, *or* tries to use it, they'll get a clear compiler error.